# Data-import to MySQL -> values vs no-values

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have following problem:

I parse a CSV file and then the data should automatically get uploaded to a MySQL database. Now the problem is that i have the datatypes "varchar" or "decimal". Here at stackoverflow I have already gotten help that if the data type is "decimal" then there stand only the number in the records.

The records (rec) look like this:

```
[ { examplename1: 'example1',
    examplename2: 'example2',
    examplename3: 'example3',
    examplename4: 'example4',
    examplename5: 'example5',
    examplename6: 'example6',
    examplename7: 'example7',
    examplename8: 'example8',
    examplename9: 'example9',
    examplename10: 'example10',
    examplename11: 'example11',
    examplename12: 'example12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: -103600, 
    examplename14: 'example14',
    Marktwert_NPV: -111146.16,
    examplename16: 'example16' },
  { examplename1: 'example1',
    examplename2: 'example2',
    examplename3: 'example3',
    examplename4: 'example4',
    examplename5: 'example5',
    examplename6: 'example6',
    examplename7: 'example7',
    examplename8: 'example8',
    examplename9: 'example9',
    examplename10: 'example10',
    examplename11: 'example11',
    examplename12: 'example12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 53851.33, 
    examplename14: 'example14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 47328.16,
    examplename16: 'example16' } ]
```

You can see that in "Diff_In_Hauswaehrung" and "Marktwert_NPV" there stand a number without ''.

These are also displayed in yellow in the console.

Now i want to check if there is such a number or only a string with '' and if there is a number then i want no "" around this value in the SQL Query.

Now i have a forEach loop where all values are uploaded with ""... but no distinction takes place... keysY are only the keys of the rec.

```
 rec.forEach(entry => {

                    values = `"${entry[keysY[0]]}"`

                    for (var i = 1; i < keysY.length; i++) {
                        values += `,"${entry[keysY[i]]}"`
                    }

                    //console.log(values)

                    var sql = `INSERT INTO ${richtigername} (${namen}) VALUES (${values})`;

                    connection.query(sql, [values], (error, response) => {

                    console.log(error || response);
```

I hope you can help me :)

Best regards,

Frederic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a value contains a valid number cast it to a `Number`. If the value is not a number the result of that cast is `false`, otherwise it's `number`. Next, check if the result is (not) a number using `isNaN`. If the result is false it is a number. To simplify this add a `!` beforehand to negate the final result.

Here's an example:

```
!isNaN(Number("12.2"))
// returns true (valid number)

!isNaN(Number("asdf12"))
// returns false (no valid number)

!isNaN(Number(12))
// returns true (valid number)
```

---

So in your case this should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 1; i < keysY.length; i++) {
    if(!isNaN(Number(${entry[keysY[i]]}) {
        // it's a number, no quotes:
        values += `,${entry[keysY[i]]}`;
    } else {
        // it's not a number (NaN) add quotes:
        values += `,"${entry[keysY[i]]}"`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks :) but i have empty columns and I solve it with typeof because then the empty columns are "strings".. with isNaN(Number() also empty columns are displayed as "false" but must be "true" or only with Number() empty columns are not NaN..

```
rec.forEach(entry => {

                    if (typeof entry[keysY[0]] == "string") {

                        values = `"${entry[keysY[0]]}"`

                    } else {

                        values = entry[keysY[0]]

                    }

                    for (var i = 1; i < keysY.length; i++) {


                        if (typeof entry[keysY[i]] == "string") {


                            values += `,"${entry[keysY[i]]}"`;

                        } else {

                            values += `,${entry[keysY[i]]}`;
                        }
```

the $ and ` are only needed if i want something like to put this in quotation marks or to put a comma in front of.